# android layout - does not display buttons according to xml layout

Tags: android, button, layout

I am trying to display correctly my buttons in a stopwatch layout ( clock, start, stop, reset, save )  I created the layout to have first the start button displayed , then programmatically I hide/display the corresponding button...

my layout xml, is designed to start displaying the START button only, checking the Graphical layout in ADT is fine....
but it keeps displaying the RESET/SAVE  2 buttons in same background)

where am I wrong ??  here is the xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/backgroundText"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/timerbackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timer"
                style="@style/timerText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/timer" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonarea"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/startButton"
                style="@style/buttonText"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/startbuttonstates"
                android:onClick="startClick"
                android:shadowColor="#FBEBC5"
                android:text="@string/startText"
                android:textColor="#5F3A00"
                android:visibility="visible" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stopButton"
                style="@style/buttonText"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/stopbuttonstates"
                android:onClick="stopClick"
                android:shadowColor="#DF726E"
                android:text="@string/stopText"
                android:textColor="#7A1100"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/resetButton"
                style="@style/buttonText"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/resetbuttonstates"
                android:onClick="resetClick"
                android:shadowColor="#959597"
                android:text="@string/resetText"
                android:textColor="#2E2E2E"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                style="@style/buttonText"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/savebuttonstates"
                android:onClick="saveClick"
                android:shadowColor="#959597"
                android:text="@string/saveText"
                android:textColor="#5F3A00"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/adsText"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

then I have 3 methods to be used programmatically when detecting user click on corresponding buttons

```
   private void showStartButton(){
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.resetButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

}

```
private void showStopButton(){
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.resetButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

}

```
private void showSaveResetButtons(){
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.resetButton)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I have been spending 2 hours trying to reboot my device, remove the app... but always starting wit RESET/SAVE buttons....

thanks for your help

Comment: Please show your onCreate();

Comment: Have you tried removing your custom style?  That may be broken, causing the buttons to disappear.

Comment: Thanks Evan you gave me a hint... I looked into  onCreate() many times , but I totally forgot to look into onResume() which was collapsed in my ADT...  the error was there, calling the wrong method ..  you deserve one vote if you enter it as answer ... ( not as a comment )